# MVC 5 Application connecting to SQL Server : Select permission denied

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, ado.net-entity-data-model

I have an MVC application that connects to SQL Server (I used a database first setup with ADO.NET Entity Framework 6.0).  When I debug on my laptop it connects to the SQL Server correctly and renders the page without issue.  But when I publish and connect to the remote server (which also is hosting the SQL Server instance) I get an error: `Select permission was denied`.  Of note is that this is set up to only work when connected to the corporate network (or with a VPN), and the server is intranet only.

I have been looking at potential solutions, and the user account on the database has `db_datareader` and `db_datawriter` permissions.  My connection string calls for `integrated security=True`.

I access this same database from desktop applications using those settings with no issues, so I am thinking that there is a difference with the way IIS is evaluating the user.

The server is set up to assign everyone into a single account for the purposes of database access, so all of the `DOMAIN\USERS` are mapped into a single account called `DOMAIN\MyDatabaseUser`.

This user has the correct permissions in the database/security/users property window.

I took a look at an answer for a similar issue that referred to the IIS Application Pool, but that issue was getting login failure, which I am not seeing.

Here is my connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="PMToolsEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.PMToolsModel.csdl|res://*/Models.PMToolsModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.PMToolsModel.msl;
provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
provider connection string=&quot;
data source=SERVER\MySQLExpressInstance;initial catalog=MyDatabase;
integrated security=True;
MultipleActiveResultSets=True;
App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

I have tried setting integrated security to `SSPI` but I get the same result.  I also, for grins, removed the integrated security setting entirely and then I get a login failure (login failed for user '') as expected.

Here is what the permissions look like for `MyDatabaseUser`:

[image: Database role memberships]

I basically added everything except the deny items to be sure, but I'm not getting in still.

Comment: If the user has any explicit `DENY` permissions, they won't be able to access the data. Also, you omitted the query, but I *assume* that you aren't using a cross database query. Also, it's a *really* bad idea for your application to have that many permissions in my opinion. It's very unlikely it needs for that `db_datareader` and `db_datawriter`, and (possibly) `db_ddladmin`, if EF is creating and altering the object in the database.

Comment: @Larnu Thanks for the reply, I agree regarding the permissions, just trying everything at this point.  I really suspect that somehow IIS on the remote server is just not getting the user correctly.  Something about the IIS Express on my localhost serving up the user differently than the proper IIS on the server.

Comment: well, the connection will be made by whatever service account IIS is running under, as you're using `integrated security=True;`

Comment: @Larnu Thanks again.  I followed up with that and found an article that indicates a possible fix would be to specify `User Instance=True` which comes with other issues.  It seems that the Application Pool Identity is what is at play here, and I don't have permissions to start playing with this.  It seems like I need the Application Pool Identity to be `MyDatabaseUser`.

Comment: You probably want to create a domain service account that runs your app pool with minimum security.  And then assign that domain account the proper permissions in the SQL server instance you are connecting to.

Comment: @Fran Thanks I'll try to get the IT guys to do that for me.  Will it be possible to simply use the group account that already exists to be the account that runs the app pool?

Comment: group account won't work here.  integrated security means that sql server is using the domain's authentication to verify the user.  in a workgroup setting that central authentication mechanism is missing. [Here's a good primer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/authentication-in-sql-server)

Comment: @Fran see the link I reference in my answer below.  Is this what you were referring to in your comment above?  It seems that the Application Pool was created automatically by Windows Server (or perhaps IIS) when the site was created . . . so each site will automatically have its own application pool.  And there is no real need for the domain service account as these application pools get assigned to a virtual account.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericparvin/2015/04/14/how-to-add-the-applicationpoolidentity-to-a-sql-server-login/) is a link to what ultimately helped me (along with a patient IT guy who let me browse around on the server that I wouldn't normally have access to).

On Windows Server 2012, in the IIS MMC snap in I could see that my web site had an Application Pool added specifically for the site called MySite.  Windows automatically creates a virtual user that needs to be added to the SQL Server Logins (not the database users) called IIS APPPOOL\MySite.  The trick is that you must not use the search function in SSMS as it will replace IIS APPPOOL with the ServerName and therefore fail to resolve the account.

Comment: I'd still create a domain service account